# Output of the program changes with printf() statement

Tags: c, arrays, undefined-behavior

Below is a C program to find the equilibrium point in the given array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void equilibrium(int a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    int rsum[n], lsum[n];

    lsum[0] = a[0];
    rsum[0] = a[n-1];
    for (i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
        lsum[i] = lsum[i-1]+a[i];
    }
    printf("lsum array: ");

    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        printf("%d ",lsum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nrsum array: ");

    for (i = n - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        rsum[i] = rsum[i + 1] + a[i];
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        printf("%d ", rsum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
        if (lsum[i] == rsum[i])
            printf("\n\n%d is equilibrium point", i);

    }
}

int main() 
{
    int a[8] = {-1,3,-4,5,1,-6,2,1};
    //printf("\n\n");
    equilibrium(a,8);
    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs as below which is correct:

```
lsum array: -1 2 -2 3 4 -2 0 1
rsum array: 1 2 -1 3 -2 -3 3 1

1 is equilibrium point
3 is equilibrium point
7 is equilibrium point
```

---

The problem occurs when I uncomment the

```
printf("\n\n");
```

in the `main()` function.

Now the output changes as follows:

```
lsum array: -1 2 -2 3 4 -2 0 1
rsum array: -45602127 -45602126 -45602129 -45602125 -45602130 -45602131 -4560212
5 -45602127
```

---

If I include another int variable, say "`int value = 1`" before declaring the "`int a[8]`" array, the output changes to:

```
lsum array: -1 2 -2 3 4 -2 0 1

rsum array: 3 4 1 5 0 -1 5 3
```

---

Is this something to do with the memory?

Can someone please give a valid reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger or add more `printf()` statements to see what your code is doing.

Comment: That is usually due to undefined behavior, somewhere else in your code that is not related to the `printf()` statement. The `printf()` statement simply changes the generated code thus making the program behave differently, that is why it's called undefined behavior because it really depends on things that are not related to the code that has it.

Comment: `rsum[i+1]` for `i=n-1` check your indice !

Comment: @meninx even if the index is fixed, it still accesses uninitialized value within the array bound. There would also need to be a change to set up the 'first' value.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing out the mistake.
@M.M Yes, I fixed that too. `rsum[0] = a[n-1];` should've been `rsum[n-1] = a[n-1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the user @[xing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2669042/xing) pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238660/output-of-the-program-changes-with-printf-statement#comment71636440_42238660), your code is accesing the array beyond bounds. Because in the first iteration of the corresponding loop, the line

```
rsum[i + 1] + a[i]
```

is accessing `rsum` at `n`, and that is 1 position after the end of `rsum`. This will cause what is known undefined behavior.

The effect of adding or removing `printf()` simply changes the memory layout of the resulting program, the same thing that happens when you define another variable. In fact, any change to the memory layout of the program affects it's behavior, thus the word *undefined*.

Answer (score 3):

In this loop

```
for (i = n - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    rsum[i] = rsum[i+1]+a[i];
              ^^^^^^^^
```

there is an access memory beyond the array bounds. Thus the result depends on what is stored in the memory after the array.

Comment: "*there is an access memory beyond the array bounds*", so?

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi And what so? Are you waiting the phrase about undefined behavior? It is clear without the phrase to all except you.

Comment: Basically the last value gets it's answer from a memory address that was not initialized, and that propagates to the rest of the array. So you are getting indeterministic value depending on what's in that address.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's just a poor answer because you don't explain why adding or removing the `printf()` causes a different behavior. If the OP knew, I don't think there would be a question at all.

Comment: @ Iharob Al Asimi It is not adding or removing the printf causes the different behavior. It is access beyond the array causes the unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @preethamkotagi [xing](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2669042/xing) already did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238660/output-of-the-program-changes-with-printf-statement#comment71636440_42238660), so this could have been a comment as well. An answer should explain why this is wrong, not just point it out. It doesn't matter how many times it has been explained, if the poster thinks that it will be redundant then find a duplicate question and vote to close this one.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi As I already said it is clear for all except you why this is wrong.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi I read the question and pointed out the reason. What else?

Comment: The question says, commenting out `printf()` makes the program behave correctly? Why is that Vlad?

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi  I am sorry I do not want to spend my time with you. Have a nice day.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the code and it is working even with `printf()` and other statements now.
What still bothers me is that the program behaved correctly without the `printf()` statement. Any explanation for that?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I really wanted you to simply improve the answer, and not for you or your reputation, but for this site's quality. Which far from what you can see in the [tag:c] tag, is really bad in other languages or specific platforms like android or PHP.