# Norm of Memoryview - Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython, precision, memoryview

I have a function that is given a memoryview vector and I want to calculate the norm of that vector. Until now I achieved that by converting the memoryview to a Numpy array and calculating the norm via `np.sqrt(V.dot(V))`. Now I want to get rid of that step for speed reasons but the program fails at some point with the following implementation.

```
cdef do_something(np.double_t[::1] M_mem):
    cdef:
        int i
        np.double_t norm_mv = 0
        np.double_t norm_np = 0
        np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] V = np.copy(np.asarray(M_mem))

    # Original implementation -- working
    norm_np = np.sqrt(V.dot(V))

    # My failed try with memoryview -- not working
    for i in range(M_mem.shape[0]):
        norm_mv += M_mem[i]**2
    norm_mv = np.sqrt(norm_mv)

    # norm_mv != norm_np
```

I suspect the reason for this is the [Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) that gets in the way for sufficiently large vectors. Is there a numerically stable way to calculate the norm of a Cython memoryview?

**UPDATE**

After checking it turns out that the rounding error is probably meaningless. Instead there is a really weird thing going on. My actual function looks like this:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef np.double_t[:,::1] GS_coefficients(np.double_t[:,::1] M_mem):
    cdef:
        int n, i, k
        int N_E = M_mem.shape[1]
        np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] W = np.asarray(M_mem)
        np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] V = np.copy(W)
        np.double_t[:,::1] G = np.eye(N_E, dtype=np.float64)
        np.longdouble_t norm  = 0 # np.sqrt(V[:,0].dot(V[:,0]))
    for i in range(M_mem.shape[0]):
        norm += M_mem[i,0]**2
    norm = sqrt(norm)
    print("npx: ", np.sqrt(V[:,0].dot(V[:,0]))) # line 1
    print("cp: ", norm) # line 2
    V[:,0] /= norm
    G[0,0] /= norm
    for n in range(1, N_E):
        for i in range(0, n):
            G[n,i] = - (V[:,i].dot(W[:,n]))
            V[:,n] += G[n,i] * V[:,i]
        norm = np.sqrt(V[:,n].dot(V[:,n]))
        V[:,n] /= norm
        for i in range(n+1):
            G[n,i] /= norm
    return G
```

I inserted the `print` statements to check "how equal" the to results for `norm` were. The stange thing is now that everything works fine as the code above stands. But when I comment out the first print statement (line 1) the code runs through the function fine, but fails shortly after in the program. What is going on there? Isn't this just a `print` statement that shouldn't even affect anything else operationally?

**UPDATE 2**

Here comes my attempt at a minimal, complete and verifiable example:

```
DEF N_E_cpt = 4

cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
from libc.math cimport sqrt

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef np.double_t[:,::1] GS_coefficients(np.double_t[:,::1] M_mem):
    """Writes the coefficients, that the Gram-Schmidt procedure
    provides in a Matrix and retruns it."""
    cdef:
        int n, i, k
        int N_E = M_mem.shape[1]
        np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] W = np.asarray(M_mem)
        np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] V = np.copy(W)
        np.double_t[:,::1] G = np.eye(N_E, dtype=np.float64)
        np.longdouble_t norm  = 0 # np.sqrt(V[:,0].dot(V[:,0]))
    for i in range(M_mem.shape[0]):
        norm += M_mem[i,0]**2
    norm = sqrt(norm)
    print("npx: ", np.sqrt(V[:,0].dot(V[:,0]))) # line 1
    print("cp: ", norm) # line 2
    V[:,0] /= norm
    G[0,0] /= norm
    for n in range(1, N_E):
        for i in range(0, n):
            G[n,i] = - (V[:,i].dot(W[:,n]))
            V[:,n] += G[n,i] * V[:,i]
        norm = np.sqrt(V[:,n].dot(V[:,n]))
        V[:,n] /= norm
        for i in range(n+1):
            G[n,i] /= norm
    return G

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef np.double_t[:,::1] G_mat(np.double_t[:,::1] M_mem):
    """Calls GS_coefficients and uses the coefficients to calculate
    the entries of the transformation matrix G_ij"""
    cdef:
        np.double_t[:,::1] G_mem = GS_coefficients(M_mem)
        int N_E = G_mem.shape[1]
        np.double_t carr[N_E_cpt][N_E_cpt]
        np.double_t[:,::1] G = carr
        int n, i, j

    # delete lower triangle in G
    G[...] = G_mem
    for i in range(N_E_cpt):
        for j in range(0, i):
            G[i,j] = 0.

    for n in range(1, N_E):
        for i in range(0, n):
            for j in range(0, i+1):
                G[n,j] += G_mem[n,i] * G[i,j]
    return G


def run_test():
    cdef:
        np.double_t[:,::1] A_mem
        np.double_t[:,::1] G
        np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] A = np.random.rand(400**2, N)
        int N = 4

    A_mem = A
    G = G_mat(A_mem)
    X = np.zeros((400**2, N))
    for i in range(0, N):
        for j in range(0,i+1):
            X[:,i] += G[i,j] * A[:,j]
    print(X)
    print("\n", X.T.dot(X))

run_test()
```

I don't think it's necessary to understand what that code does. The mystery for me is really why that `print` statement makes any difference.

So what this code is supposed to to is take an non-orthonormal set of vectors written as column vectors in a Matrix A and return an orthonormalization matrix which orthonormalizes the set of vectors like so:

[image: Formula for orthonormalization in code style]

So A_{orthonormal} is equivalent to the X matrix in the code. When you multiply the transpose of a orthonormal matrix with the orthonormal matrix itself you get the unity matrix, which is what you get so long as the `print` statement # line1 is in there. As soon as you remove it you also get off-diagonal entries which means the matrix is not even orthogonal. Why?

Comment: There's a typo in this: `norm` Vs `norm_mv`. Could you do l confirm that this isn't the problem?

Comment: You are correct, but that was not the problem.

Comment: I'd also test if they're close, rather than equal. It's quite likely there will be small meaningless rounding error differences between the two answers.

Comment: Yes, you are right, they are very close. I initially thought that roundoff error, though very small (16th digigt), was causing the failure. But I think you are right that this is meaningless. I now stumbled upon a really weird thing, I will update the post (though I'm not sure whether to open a new thread for this...).

Comment: `numpy.isclose(norm_mv, norm_np)` is a better way to compare floating point.

Comment: Following your edit, could you provide a "full" test case, with example input? See [mcve]

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Thank you for providing that link. I tried to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example now. The UPDATE 2 code should work just by copy and paste.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails" exactly? Crashes? Wrong result? Endless loop?

Comment: You also should heed warnings from cython/compiler: In your case N is used (`np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] A = np.random.rand(400**2, N)`) before it assigned.

Comment: @ead By crashes I mean the complete program crashes shortly after the section I provided the example for above was executed. In the snippet above the "crash" is that the off diagonal elements in 'X.T.dot(X)' are not 0 (or close to 0) anymore once I comment out the 'print' statement.

Comment: @ead You are right about the compiler warning, but changing it did not make a difference. Setting 'boundscheck=True' did make a difference though, but there is still one off-diag element that is not 0 as should be. Are there any other general dangers that I ignored?

Comment: I have found now that computing the last 'sqrt' in the 'GS_coefficients' function with 'libc.math.sqrt' instead of Numpy solves the problem. This is really strange to me. I guess it is some weird memory thing that is going on there where a 'print' statement or what function you use to compute a sqrt is changing the result of the function... Something similar happend [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238660/output-of-the-program-changes-with-printf-statement) but there it was clearly array beyond bounds which shouldn't b the case here (boundscheck(True)). Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

There is at least a typo

```
for i in range(M_mem.shape[0]):
    norm += M_mem[i]**2
```

->

```
for i in range(M_mem.shape[0]):
    norm_mv += M_mem[i]**2
```

Else, I recommend the more idiomatic version below:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport sqrt

def do_something(double[::1] M_mem):
    cdef:
        int i
        double norm_mv = 0
        double norm_np = 0
        double[::1] V = np.copy(np.asarray(M_mem))

    # Original implementation -- working
    norm_np = np.sqrt(np.dot(V, V))

    # My failed try with memoryview -- not working
    for i in range(M_mem.shape[0]):
        norm_mv += M_mem[i]**2
    norm_mv = sqrt(norm_mv)

    # norm_mv != norm_np
    return norm_np, norm_mv
```

import *and* cimport numpy and use the scalar math functions from `libc.math` instead of the NumPy versions. You can still speed up the code a bit by decorating the routine with `@cython.boundscheck(False)` (you need `cimport cython` then).

Comment: You are right about the typo. I corrected it. Is `libc.math` generally faster than numpy or just in this specific case?

Comment: Calling a function from `libc.math` on a scalar value can be compiled without "Python overhead" by Cython whereas functions from NumPy cannot. So it is faster when you operate on scalars. For array operations, I guess it depends on the array size and on the optimization of the NumPy function with respect to a naive user-implemented algorithm.